# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'targetLat' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, google-maps

well i just put some markers on google map and it works as i want and marker is displayed as required on the map but i get this error in the console i don't know why which makes the app runs on android but not on windows phone

```
function initMap() {
        var map;
        var faisalabad = { lat: 30.044281, lng: 31.340002 };

        $('#locaitonBtn').click(function () {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                    map.setCenter(latlng);
                });
            }
        })

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 10,
            center: faisalabad,
            disableDefaultUI: true
        });
        $.ajax({
            async:false,
            url: "https://someUrl",
            method: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                for (i = 0; i <= data.targets.length; i++) {
                    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.targets[i].targetLat, data.targets[i].targetLong);
                    myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                        position: myLatLng
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'click', (function (myMarker, i) {
                        return function () {
                            infowindow.setContent(data.targets[i].targetName);
                            infowindow.open(map, myMarker);
                        }
                    })(myMarker, i));
                }
            }
        })

    }
```

Comment: please make a console.log(data) in your success function. if you don't find the failure in the json, post this logged element and i'll try to help. but i think the fields are named different than you try to access or you simply have a typo

Comment: @mtizziani I took a Scree Shot of the logged data so you can see

[link](https://postimg.org/image/4m519a799/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    async:false,
    url: "https://someUrl",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        for (var i = 0; i <= data.targets.length; i++) {
            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.targets[i].targetLat, data.targets[i].targetLong);
            var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                position: myLatLng
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'click', (function (myMarker, i, data) {
                return function () {
                    infowindow.setContent(data.targets[i].targetName);
                    infowindow.open(map, myMarker);
                }
            })(myMarker, i, data));
        }
    }
});
```

changed 3 things:

1. `var i = 0` in for statement
2. `var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker ...` (it's not a global)
3. injecting `data` to the anonymous click listener function because it has no scope on the data object.

i'm not sure this works because i have no test envoirement for it. but hope it helps you to figure out the failure.

i think the first point was the failure because you tried to use a global i in your for loop and reset it anywhere else in your code. so the array index returns undefined

Comment: I tried your answer and thank you for your help, but the error is still there and it's on this line

`var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.targets[i].targetLat, data.targets[i].targetLong);`

Comment: have you checked if `i`is available in your array? `console.log(data.targets.hasOwnProperty(i));`

Comment: I tried and the respond was [link](https://postimg.org/image/qqk3seord/) you will find **Logged data** and 3 true and a false, 3 is the number of objects in the loop cause i have only 3 places that i want to show but i don't know what is this false

Answer (score 0):

Well I couldn't solve the problem or find an answer to it anywhere so i added the success function to a try catch block so it don't console the error and i can run the app now on windows phone